# Postgresql sql import Permission denied!

Tags: postgresql, centos

Can't import db from sql file

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for user: 
could not change directory to "/home/user"
Password: 
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c db
You are now connected to database "db" as user "postgres".
rob=# \i /home/user/Downloads/dump.sql
/home/user/Downloads/dump.sql: `Permission denied`



[root@localhost user]# ls -Z /home/user/Downloads/dump.sql
-rw-rw-rw-. postgres postgres unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 dump.sql
```

Q: Why `Permission denied`? How can I fix it?

CentOS 7.2.1511

Comment: the `postgres` OS user does not have access to `/home/user`.

Comment: Do you really need to import that dump as the user `postgres`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move the file into /tmp folder, I hope this will work.

In PostgreSQL you run into error with having permission on the the file but not all the folders/directories before it.

Comment: This worked for me in Centos Linux